# Accessing this variable from method instance

Tags: javascript

How do you access the this object from another object instance?

```
var containerObj = {
    Person: function(name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
containerObj.Person.prototype.Bag = function(color){
    this.color = color;
}
containerObj.Person.prototype.Bag.getOwnerName(){
    return name; //I would like to access the name property of this instance of Person
}

var me = new Person("Asif");
var myBag = new me.Bag("black");
myBag.getOwnerName()// Want the method to return Asif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put the constructor on the prototype of another class. Use a factory pattern:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
Person.prototype.makeBag = function(color) {
    return new Bag(color, this);
};

function Bag(color, owner) {
    this.color = color;
    this.owner = owner;
}
Bag.prototype.getOwnerName = function() {
    return this.owner.name;
};

var me = new Person("Asif");
var myBag = me.makeBag("black");
myBag.getOwnerName() // "Asif"
```

Related patterns to deal with this problem: [Prototype for private sub-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9982562/1048572), [Javascript - Is it a bad idea to use function constructors within closures?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18761947/1048572)

Comment: @MrCode: Thanks, of course it should. I wouldn't have minded if you just edited the post :-)

Comment: I set me.name = "Smo" after calling the makeBag method. Then myBag.getOwnerName() returns John. That's what I want it to do but why does that happen? I mean, why is this.owner changed when the object passed in is changed?

Comment: The `this.downer` property is not changed, it still is ("points to") the `me` obj. But that object is mutated!